# Encode client request params in Node.js

Tags: http, encoding, node.js

I **need a method/implementation in Node.js** that get a hash or array, and transform it to the HTML request param, just like [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1, 
    two: 2, 
    three: 3
  }, 
  b: [1,2,3]
}; // => "a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3"
```

*I just cant use it from jQuery since it depends on Browser native implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know such native function or module but you can use this one:

```js
// Query String able to use escaping
var query = require('querystring');

function toURL(object, prefix)
{
  var result = '',
    key = '',
    postfix = '&';

  for (var i in object)
  {
    // If not prefix like a[one]...
    if ( ! prefix)
    {
      key = query.escape(i);
    }
    else
    {
      key = prefix + '[' + query.escape(i) + ']';
    }

    // String pass as is...
    if (typeof(object[i]) == 'string')
    {
      result += key + '=' + query.escape(object[i]) + postfix;
      continue;
    }

    // objectects and arrays pass depper
    if (typeof(object[i]) == 'object' || typeof(object[i]) == 'array')
    {
      result += toURL(object[i], key) + postfix;
      continue;
    }

    // Other passed stringified
    if (object[i].toString)
    {
      result += key + '=' + query.escape(object[i].toString()) + postfix;
      continue;
    }
  }
  // Delete trailing delimiter (&) Yep it's pretty durty way but
  // there was an error gettin length of the objectect;
  result = result.substr(0, result.length - 1);
  return result;
}

// try
var x = {foo: {a:{xxx:9000},b:2}, '[ba]z': 'bob&jhonny'};
console.log(toURL(x));
// foo[a]=1&foo[b]=2&baz=bob%26jhonny
```

Comment: there is an error where you wrote: `typeof(object[i]) == 'objectect'`, should be `'object'` to do recursion

Comment: Also, please note this example is failing: `var x = {foo: {a:{xxx:9000},b:2}, baz: 'bob&jhonny'};` due double encoding

Comment: Bugs fixed :) One last feature is that arrays keys is passed with numbers: b[1]=1, not b[]=1 to avoid problems

Comment: Nice! was even able to parse with numbers :) `{foo: {a:{xxx:9000, c:{omg:'zombies'}} ,b:2}, 'baz': 'bob&jhonny '};` while `qs.stringify` failed with numbers, I'd suggest you submit your code as path